# Retrieving account in google glass using GDK

Tags: java, google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

My glassware is requiring user account credentials so I use [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication) to authenticate a user. I'm successfully inserting user account with [this](https://gist.github.com/LubnaEssa/c7c076fc9e440f0cdd52#file-gistfile1-txt). However when I'm retrieving the account, i'm getting this

```
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726): android.accounts.OperationCanceledException
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.internalGetResult(AccountManager.java:1503)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1531)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1452)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at info.genix.glass.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:108)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$11.run(AccountManager.java:1427)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-16 08:57:36.580: W/System.err(22726):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I already did the same solution came from Alain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631301/retrieve-the-auth-token-in-gdk). But still getting the same error.

CODE:

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    // Use your Glassware's account type.
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);//Already approved by google
    if (accounts != null && accounts.length > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity Account");
        for (int i =0;i<accounts.length;i++)
        {     
            accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[i], "randomType", null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                     try {
                          Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity AccountManagerFuture");
                          String email  = future.getResult().getString("email");
                          String uname  = future.getResult().getString("uname");
                          Log.d(TAG, email+" "+dbname+" "+uname);
                          String token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                          Log.d("token","token :-"+ token);
                            // Use the token.
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                                // Handle exception.
                                e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                 }
            }, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `info.genix.glass` the package name you provided when you submitted your Glassware for review?

Comment: Yes. Also the accountType is info.genix.glass and approved.

Comment: What is on this line: `info.genix.glass.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:108)`?

Comment: String email  = future.getResult().getString("email");

Comment: I see. Can you comment out `email` and `uname`? I want to see if the error also occurs on the `getString` on `KEY_AUTHTOKEN`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error sir.

Comment: i forgot to include this error. (04-22 08:37:20.658: I/AccountManagerService(494): Sharing credentials is not allowed: canceling.
)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay. One reason could be that you used a different certificate when you submitted your APK for review and the one you use for testing. Here's what you could try to do:

1. Turn off your Glassware on MyGlass and wait for Glass to sync and remove the Glassware from the device.
2. Uninstall the version of your Glassware still on your device (`adb uninstall <package name>`).
3. Turn on the Glassware on MyGlass. Wait for Glass to sync and install it.
4. This should already be working. If you have new versions, you can still deploy locally, but make sure to use the same certificate/key.

Comment: What do you mean by using the same certificate/key?

Comment: Can I have some steps how to do that?

Comment: When I install the version of my glassware it gives me "Failure"

Comment: I already did all the steps you said, but when I install my local glassware in adb it says "MIssing APK file".